# how to add active class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can you please tell me how to add active class in jQuery. So that user know it is selected and unselected button?

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/GG7ZZ/48/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#btn").addClass('highlight')
  });
});
```

Comment: do you mean: `$(this).toggleClass('highlight')` ??? http://jsfiddle.net/GG7ZZ/50/

Comment: actually if user click it should highlight , if user remove unfocus it  remove hightlight color

Comment: No it is hightlighted when user remove focus

Comment: when user press it should highlight but when it remove focus it should remove highlight

Comment: @user944513 then http://jsfiddle.net/GG7ZZ/53/  `#btn:focus {
        background: yellow;
    }`

Comment: See my answer below. You don't even need Javascript for it. You can do it with HTML and CSS alone.

Comment: Next time, improve your question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/GG7ZZ/52/

```
   button:active {
       background: yellow;
   }
```

You don't even need javascript for this. Just add the above CSS and it'll do what you want.

Comment: pseudo class `:focus` seems more accurate even OP has posted a really unclear question

Comment: I think he said when the user presses the button. But yes in the later part, he has also said when the user removes focus. So, we can't decide what is it that he wanted.